# Consensus and execution clients communication problem in Gnosis node

Tags: docker, ethereum, execution, lighthouse, consensus

I'm trying to run a node on the Gnosis blockchain. I used the link below to install Sedge, which has an interactive mode for installing the execution and consensus clients. I installed Nethermind and Lighthouse.
https://docs.sedge.nethermind.io/docs/quickstart/complete-guide

From my disk space, I see that the clients downloaded around 350GB of data. But when I open the logs, here is the message:

`sedge-execution-client  | 08 Feb 09:01:40 | No incoming messages from the consensus client that is required for sync.`

Also, this one: `sedge-consensus-client  | Feb 08 09:04:37.502 WARN Syncing deposit contract block cache    est_blocks_remaining: initializing deposits, service: slot_notifier sedge-consensus-client  | Feb 08 09:04:42.501 WARN Low peer count                          peer_count: 0, service: slot_notifier sedge-consensus-client  | Feb 08 09:04:42.501 WARN Head is optimistic                      execution_block_hash: 0x2fac9ad9866eefd1b4da7a39ca0a420e905bf09647b091f2b91c2e9192c65ea5, info: chain not fully verified, block and attestation production disabled until execution engine syncs, service: slot_notifier`

This is what I have in the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
services:
  execution:
    tty: true
    environment:
    - TERM=xterm-256color
    - COLORTERM=truecolor
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    container_name: sedge-execution-client
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: ${EC_IMAGE_VERSION}
    networks:
    - sedge
    volumes:
    - ${EC_DATA_DIR}:/nethermind/data
    - ${EC_JWT_SECRET_PATH}:/tmp/jwt/jwtsecret
    ports:
    - 30303:30303/tcp
    - 30303:30303/udp
    - 8008:8008
    - 8545:8545
    - 8551:8551
    expose:
    - 8545
    - 8551
    command:
    - --config=${EL_NETWORK}
    - --datadir=/nethermind/data
    - --log=${NETHERMIND_LOG_LEVEL}
    - --JsonRpc.Enabled=true
    - --JsonRpc.Host=0.0.0.0
    - --JsonRpc.Port=8545
    - --JsonRpc.JwtSecretFile=/tmp/jwt/jwtsecret
    - --JsonRpc.EngineHost=0.0.0.0
    - --JsonRpc.EnginePort=8551
    - --Network.DiscoveryPort=30303
    - --HealthChecks.Enabled=true
    - --Metrics.Enabled=true
    - --Metrics.ExposePort=8008
  consensus:
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    container_name: sedge-consensus-client
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: ${CC_IMAGE_VERSION}
    networks:
    - sedge
    volumes:
    - ${CC_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/lighthouse
    - ${CC_JWT_SECRET_PATH}:/tmp/jwt/jwtsecret
    ports:
    - 9000:9000/tcp
    - 9000:9000/udp
    - 5054:5054/tcp
    - 4000:4000
    expose:
    - 4000
    command:
    - lighthouse
    - bn
    - --disable-upnp
    - --datadir=/var/lib/lighthouse
    - --port=9000
    - --http
    - --http-address=0.0.0.0
    - --http-port=4000
    - --network=${CL_NETWORK}
    - --target-peers=${CC_PEER_COUNT}
    - --execution-endpoints=${EC_AUTH_URL}
    - --execution-jwt=/tmp/jwt/jwtsecret
    - --eth1-endpoints=${EC_API_URL}
    - --debug-level=${CC_LOG_LEVEL}
    - --validator-monitor-auto
    - --subscribe-all-subnets
    - --import-all-attestations
    - --metrics
    - --metrics-port=5054
    - --metrics-address=0.0.0.0
    - --checkpoint-sync-url=https://checkpoint.gnosischain.com
networks:
  sedge:
    name: sedge-network
```

and `netstat -lutu` returns this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5054            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:1635          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:sunrpc          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30303           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8545            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8551            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8008               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5054               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:4000               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:smtp      [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30303              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8545               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8551               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9000               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                                                    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:sunrpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30303           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:9000               [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:30303              [::]:*
```

I don't understand what is wrong here. Any help is highly appreciated.